# How to assign individual labels to values on the axes in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, octave, matlab-figure

I have a matrix in matlab. Each row/column has a unique label. these labels are in a row-matrix. How do I print these labels on the figure next to that row/column number? Nevermind the cluminess in display, I want to see the labels against the rows rather than the row numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have a plot like

```
pcolor(magic(4));
```

and labels similar to

```
lbl = ['a'; 'b'; 'c'; 'd'];
```

Following my example you have four labels for both X and/or Y. All you need to do from here is set the XTicks of your axes to the number of lables you have, then set the XTickLabels like so:

```
set(gca,'XTick',1:length(lbl),'XTickLabel',lbl)
```